# LÖVE `point` is not callable

Tags: love2d

```
function love.draw()
   love.graphics.point( 20, 20 )
end
```

should work according to https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.point. But in 0.10.1 on OSX I get

```
Error: main.lua:2: attempt to call field 'point' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    main.lua:2: in function 'draw'
    [string "boot.lua"]:467: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:435>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

the star field example provided under the link leads to the same error on the point call by the way. What gives? Is LÖVE broken or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I missed the "removed" notification under the same link.